# Read ChildSnaphot Value in Firebase but without forEach

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a code about chatting with firebase. I have a login and I use my code foreach because I want read childsnaphot values but there is a lot of data in the database therefore the checking process takes too long.

My code:

```
$("#giris").click(function() {
    var emailgrs = $("#eposta").val();
    var passgrs = $("#pass").val();
    var adgrs = $("#ad").val();
    if (emailgrs != " " && passgrs != " " && adgrs != " ") {
        var query = firebase.database().ref("users");
        query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var data = childSnapshot.val();
                var usename = data.username;
                var pass = data.pass;
                var email = data.email;
                if (emailgrs == email && passgrs == pass && adgrs == usename) {
                    //alert("Başarılı");
                    $("#girisEkrani").hide();
                    $("#chatEkrani").show();
                    $("#kayıtEkrani").hide();
                    $("#kontrolEkrani").hide();
                    chatYukle();
                } //else {
                //     alert("Başarısız, Başkalarının hesabına girmeye çalışıyorsan sakın deneme!!");
                // }
            });

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Okey I know but I want the code to be faster and everything works

Comment: Without seeing your existing code, data and debugging results (such as how long everything takes), it's impossible to help. Please read the link I provided for guidance that will increase the chance that someone can help.

Comment: Assume 1 million users but forEach 1 million users will find their data. I guess this process about 30 minutes because I'm here in Turkey and the US are connecting to the server.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I send my code

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared looks unusual, so it is unlikely that the slowness comes from there. Check how much data you're downloading, compare that to your internet speed, and see if that explains the time it takes. Without seeing more information (as asked before) there is not a lot we can do for you here.

Comment: Thank you for your interest